# Memory allocation and deallocation in separate module

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Dynamic_Array

Use Variables
Use Allocation_Module
Use Dealloaction_Module

Implicit none

Call Subroutine_0

Call Subroutine_1

End Program Dynamic_Array

Module Variables

Implicit none

Integer :: i , k
Integer , parameter :: Br_sn_cvo = 10
Integer , parameter :: Br_nn_mre = 7
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_nn_mre) :: Br_nn_cvo = [ 7 , 6 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 ]
Integer , dimension ( Br_nn_mre ) :: i_nn_dm_1 , i_nn_dm_2

type :: my_type

     integer, allocatable :: my_size(:)

end type my_type

type(my_type), allocatable :: dS_sn(:)

End Module Variables

Module Allocation_Module

Use Variables

Implicit none

Contains

Subroutine Subroutine_0

Allocate(dS_sn(Br_nn_mre))

Loop_1: Do k = 1, Br_nn_mre

        i_nn_dm_1(k) = Br_sn_cvo + Br_nn_mre + 1 + Br_nn_cvo(k) * ( k - 1 )
        i_nn_dm_2(k) = Br_sn_cvo + Br_nn_mre + k * Br_nn_cvo(k)

        Allocate( dS_sn(k)%my_size( i_nn_dm_1(k) : i_nn_dm_2(k)) )

        Loop_2: Do i = i_nn_dm_1(k) , i_nn_dm_2(k)

                   dS_sn(k)%my_size(i) = i + k

                End Do Loop_2

        End do loop_1

End subroutine Subroutine_0

End Module Allocation_Module

Module Dealloaction_Module

Use Variables

Implicit none

Contains

Subroutine Subroutine_1

Do k = 1 , Br_nn_mre

   Deallocate(dS_sn(k)%my_size)

End do

   Deallocate(dS_sn)

Return
End Subroutine Subroutine_1

End Module Dealloaction_Module
```

I am not experienced programer in Fortran so I need to ask a few questions about process of memory allocation and deallocation for a dynamic arrays. Is there any problem with memory leak in this code? 
Is this correct way for a memory allocation in separate module?
Is this correct way for a memory deallocation in separate module?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add [tag:fortran95] but  consider whether you really want to limit yourself to this old standard. You already got an answer in Fortran 2008 elsewhere today. Also note that more indentation would really help the readability of your code (too see where each module or subroutine begins and ends).

Comment: Even more, your code is not even Fortran 95 compliant, there were no allocatable components in Fortran 95 proper. They are Fortran 2003. I removed the `fortran95` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no memory leak in the code. It is impossible to make a memory leak with `allocatable` entities in Fortran. Only `pointer` can cause a memory leak.

With allocatable if something is going out of scope, it is deallocated automatically.

Your main array is a module variable so it is never going  out of scope (it is `save` implicitly by Fortran 2008 rules). So if you don't deallocate it yourself, it will remain allocated and then deleted by the operating system on the program termination. But that is *not* normally considered to be a memory leak. It is not really harmful, because there is no way to make some forgotten copies of the array in memory.

The individual components `my_size` could go out of scope, when deallocating the large array `dS_sn`. In that case they are deallocated automatically by Fortran rules. You don't have to deallocate them one by one.

So you do not really have to do

```
Do k = 1 , Br_nn_mre

   Deallocate(dS_sn(k)%my_size)

End do
```

Doing just

```
Deallocate(dS_sn)
```

is perfectly correct.

Comment: I understand that but what if i want to make a deallocation of arrays from my code, what if i want to learn how to do that correctly? Is this way of deallocation in separet module formaly correct?

Comment: Correct in which sense? You can do the deallocation wherever you want. It depends on the specific situation. Sometimes you need it from a specific module subroutine, sometimes you need it during some computation in some specific place.

Comment: In sense that i want to learn how to use dealloacation command in separate module for allocatable array in my code. I just want to now how to use deallocation command in this case. That is all!

Comment: You just used it. It is in your code. `Deallocate(dS_sn)`, there is nothing more to it. You can call it from wherever you see `dS_sn` as an allocatable variable, so wherever you `use` the module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example...

...

```
IF(ALLOCATED(TheArray)) THEN
  IF(SIZE(TheArray) /= The_Size_I_need) DEALLOCATE(TheArray)
ENDIF
IF(.NOT.  ALLOCATED(TheArray)) ALLOCATE(TheArray(The_Size_I_need))
```

This is useful if the array gets used repeatedly for different processing sizes.

If it is "always" fixed in terms of the current execution, then there is no real need to do anything.